# VueJS is causing CSS animations to load again?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS with Laravel, and when I include VueJS, it looks like the page is reparsed/rerendered when Vue is loaded causing all my CSS animations (that trigger on page load) to play again. I've checked that the page is actually loaded once (by using a `console.log()` to check for duplicates and by looking at the HTTP requests, with each one called once).

When looking at the performance trace you can see when it happens, but I'm not sure why or what's causing it, or where to debug from here. [image]

Notice the background is animated but the logo is not; so the logo stays visible but the animation re-triggers.

app.js (Vue entrance)

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('chart-line-component', require('./components/ChartLineComponent.js').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

What's causing my animations to reload when Vue is included?

Update: just tried on another site with the same setup - keyframe animation on a div animates twice on page load with Vue and properly (once as it should) without Vue...

Comment: please provide your Vue.js code part (or all of your code). Where and what part of Vue are you including in your project?

Comment: @Phanti hey! I'm includingVue in the default app.js that Laravel constructed (pre version 6). The repo is here: https://github.com/M-Media-Group/m-media and I've updated the question to add the app.js

Answer (score 0):

Probably your pages load without javascript and start animations but when your javascript load Vuejs rerender that part of the dom. You can add v-cloak to your #app div.

```
<div id="app" v-cloak> 
...
</div>
```

Then you can add this CSS to your CSS files.

```
[v-cloak] { 
 display: none; 
}
```

With this way your app won't render until Vuejs load.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak